# Excel - Only keep 2 duplicates, not more

Tags: excel, duplicates

I have a list of duplicates, some are 5 versions of the same, some ten.

I want to remove all duplicates but keep two versions of the same value and no more. Can you please advise.

Answer (score 0):

If your list is in ColumnA starting in A1, you might add to Row1 of a helper column:

```
=COUNTIF(A$1:A1,A1)>2
```

and copy down to suit, then filter that helper column to select and delete rows showing `TRUE`.